# Trying to get file size in bits

Tags: binaryfiles, ifstream

Right now I have

```
ifstream argfs (argv[1], ifstream::binary | ifstream::in)
int length;
argfs.seekg(0, argfs.end);
length = argfs.tellg();
```

Pretty much I'm trying to find out how many bits are in a file, but when this runs it gives me how many bytes. How can I do this? Is this not what " ::binary " is used for?

Thanks

Comment: No, you'll get the length in characters. Try multiplying by CHAR_BIT (which I'd be highly surprised if it wasn't 8 on your system.)

Answer (score 0):

Well there are 8 bits in a byte, just multiply your result by 8 and that will be the total number of bits.

```
ifstream argfs (argv[1], ifstream::binary | ifstream::in)
int length;
argfs.seekg(0, argfs.end);
length = argfs.tellg();
length *= CHAR_BIT;  // will be 8
```

Answer (score 0):

`length=argfs.tellg();`
Returns the position of the file pointer which is basically the number of characters read by the file pointer.
note that **1 Character=1 byte**

Also one byte comprises of 8 bits so just multiply it by 8

`length = 8*argfs.tellg();`